# How can I take an image of my Raspberry Pi without all the unused space being captured?

Tags: raspberry-pi, disk-image

Only 15% of the 30GB on the Pi's SD card is being used, but even when I use `win32diskimager` and tell it to ignore the unused space, it still captures the unused space and the image file produced is 30GB in size.

How can I take an image of my Raspberry Pi without all the unused space being captured?

Comment: are you certain that the resulting image file uses 30 GB of disk space?

Comment: You could use Clonezilla

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using RPi OS (aka Raspbian), the [`image-utils` package](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils) will avoid replicating all of that *empty space* in the image file it produces.  A similar question was [asked and answered in Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790) some time ago; the answer outlines use of `image-utils`.